Why is it vscode python could not find debugpy path when running without debugging?

I'm relatively new to platforms like vscode, and I seem to run into problems whenever I try to run a python program without debugging (Ctrl + F5). A window pops up saying "Could not find debugpy path" and gives me the option of either opening launch.json or cancelling. Running from the "run file" button on the right works, so I'm just curious what is causing this problem.
I opened launch.json and it's mostly empty:
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": []
}



Googling the error message brought up this: Ctrl+F5 - could not find debugpy path Error. Someone suggested downgrading. (Note that this bug was filed on the wrong repo, VSCode instead of the Python extension.)

Turns out I needed to download a Python debugger in the VSCode extensions. I used Python Debugger from Microsoft.


I just had similar and found uninstalling & reinstalling Python Debugger fixed it

For someone who keep trying uninstall, reinstall Extensions like "Python", "Python Debugger" and still ran into this error.
I accidentally upgrade my vscode and met this error, I was trying to add a debug configuration by using IDE select: Run > Add Configuration > Select Python Debugger at the autocomplete selection.
And it pops out the new debugging configuration that I could run debugger, and the difference between new one and mine is the "type" argument
// New configuration
{ 
    "type": "debugpy",
}

// Mine configuration
{
    "type": "python",
}

So I update my old configuration type to debugpy and debugger is running.

Changing the type value to debugpy in the debug configuration inside the launch.json file also solved my issue.
